# How to reference a value of a constant from a different view Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift3

I would like to reference a value of a constant from a different view. I looked online how to do so but most of the search results are outdated or don't work.

I would like to reference the value of `oneRepMax` in a `struct ProgressiveOverload`.

I want to import `oneRepMax` from here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OneRepMaxCalculator: View {
    
    @State private var reps = 1.0
    @State private var weight = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Weight")) {
                    TextField("Weight: \(weight.formatted())kg", value: $weight, format: .number)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Reps")) {
                    Stepper("Reps : \(reps.formatted())", value: $reps, in: 1...10)
                }
                
            //THIS CONSTANT
            let oneRepMax = reps == 1.0 ? weight : weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2
                
                
                if oneRepMax > 0 {
                    Text("Your 1RM is: \(oneRepMax.formatted())kg")
                        .font(.headline)
                }

                if weight > 0 {
                Section(header: Text("2RM-10RM")) {
                    Menu("View All From 2RM-10RM") {
                        Text(String(format: "Your 2RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*2))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*2))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 3RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*3))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*3))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 4RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*4))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*4))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 5RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*5))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*5))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 6RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*6))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*6))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 7RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*7))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*7))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 8RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*8))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*8))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 9RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*9))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*9))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        Text(String(format: "Your 10RM is %.1fkg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*10))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*10))+2))
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if oneRepMax > 0 {
                    Section(header: Text("Progressive Overload")){
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProgressiveOverload()) {
                        Text("Apply Progressive Overload")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if weight == 0 && reps > 1 {
                Section(header: Text("Warning")){
                    Text("Add Weight First")
                        .font(.callout)
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        
                }
                
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("One Rep Max Calculator"))
        }
    }
}

struct OneRepMaxCalculator_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OneRepMaxCalculator()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

To here:

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct ProgressiveOverload: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Text("Your 1RM is \(oneRepMax)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressiveOverload_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressiveOverload()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it on as an argument:

```
struct ProgressiveOverload: View {
    let oneRepMax: Double
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Text("Your 1RM is \(oneRepMax)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProgressiveOverload(oneRepMax: oneRepMax)) {
    Text("Apply Progressive Overload")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that and I got an error: 
`
import SwiftUI
    
struct ProgressiveOverload: View {
    let oneRepMax : Double
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Text("Your 1RM is \(oneRepMax)")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Progressive Overload"))
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressiveOverload_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressiveOverload()     

//HERE WAS THE ERROR: Missing argument for parameter 'oneRepMax' in call, Insert 'oneRepMax: <#Double#>'

    }
}
`

Comment: @timoswipe Well you would need to provide a default value there. So... just `static var previews: some View { ProgressiveOverload(oneRepMax: 1.0)}`. Or whatever value you deem fit.